# Topological space lacking a point

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We bestow X and Y with topologies $\tau_x,\tau_y$ for a certain continuous function $f$ from $X/\{x\}$ (with subspace topology) to $Y$.

> Under which circumstances can we extend $f$ on all of $X$, $x$ included so that:
>
> 1) the new extension $f^*:X \rightarrow Y$ (which is equal to $f$ on $X/\{x\}$ ) is continuous with respect to $\tau_x$ and $\tau_y$
>
> AND (the tricky part)
>
> 2) Without resorting to the metric notion of limit (I am restating the obvious because I mentioned no norm before; if there is a limit then an extension exists but is that both a necessary and sufficient condition?)

The point is that I am trying to see how I can define an extension on a topological space, the only way I know of is in a metric space.

Comment: What extension? What metric?

Comment: @B.Pasternak I have edited the question for your convenience.

Comment: You cannot resort to the metric notion of limit if you have no metric. I also see no norms, so there are no norms to be omitted. I still don't get your question: you seem to be taking a continuous extension $f*$ of $f$, and then asking whether you can add $x$ to $X\setminus\{x\}$ without ruining the continuity of $f*$? What's the actual question, what are your precise hypotheses?

Comment: @B.Pasternak my question is general. I insisted on the lack of norm by repeating it literally. $f^*$ is rather the extension that I seek. In other terms, How can we extend $f$ to $x$ (thus defining $x$) the while we keep the continuity of the resulting extension.

Comment: in topological terms this time

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb R \setminus 0  \to \mathbb R$. If $f(x) = 1$ then it has a continuous extension by defining $f(0) = 1$, while if $f(x) = 1/x$ then it doesn't have a continuous extension. I think the question is looking for a topological non-metric characterization of functions like the first.

Comment: In other words the question is looking for a topological characterization of a removable discontinuity as opposed to an essential discontinuty.

Comment: @TomCollinge indeed. I think we can resort to a limit of intersections of Open subsets in X that include x but again those subsets are not necessarily countable but if they were then $\bigcap^n_{x \in O} O_n$ would be the equivalent of the expression $\exists \delta$, $\vert y - x \vert \leq \delta$. How could we express this if the opens are uncountable?

Comment: One possible answer is that a discontinuity at $x$ is **removable** if $\exists  y \in Y$ : for every open set $V \in\tau_y$ with $y \in V$  there is an open set set $U \in\tau_x$ with $x \in U$ and $U \setminus \{x\} \subset f^{-1}(V)$. If so then defining $f(x) = y$ gives a continuous extension of $f$ from $X \setminus \{x\}$ to $X$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2144066

Comment: @TomCollinge to give you some context. I once wrote that a connected space minus one point, remains connected. My (likely flawed) argument was that a continuous function (wrt to the subspace topology: IMPORTANT premise) from $C\{x}$ to a discrete set (say $\mathbb{N}$) is constant, if it were not then by adding x again we would find a continuous function from $C$ to  $\mathbb{N}$ wich is not constant. This is the motivation for this question. Because I do not remember why I was told that the argument was flawed.

Answer (score 0):

$f^*:X\to Y$ is continuous iff whenever $A\subset X$ and $p\in Cl_X(A)$ then $f(p)\in Cl_Y(f^*(A)).$ So there are two conditions on $f$ that are necessary & sufficient for a continuous extension  $f^*$ to exist: There must exist $y=f^*(x)\in Y$ such that

(1) whenever $x'\in Cl_X(\{x\})$ then $f(x')\in Cl_Y(\{y\}),$ and

(2) whenever $x\not \in S\subset X$ and $x\in Cl_X(S)$ then $y\in Cl_Y(f(S)).$

Remark: The usual topological def'n of continuity of $f^*:X\to Y$ is that $(f^*)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ whenever $V$ is open in $Y$. My first sentence above is one of many statements that are  equivalent  to this def'n.